What does "make" in the phrase "make + verb-ing" mean?
I found the following sentence in Oxford Advanced Learners' Dictionary:

a formal promise to be loyal to the US, which Americans make standing
in front of the flag with their right hand on their heart.

Since I've never seen "make" directly followed by a gerund like what's in this sentence before, I'm wondering what "make standing" means here?

Americans make the promise [while they are] standing in front of the flag...

You've parsed the construction incorrectly; it should be parsed as bracketed:

[a formal promise to be loyal to the US, which Americans make] [standing in front of the flag with their right hand on their heart].

The gerund-participial clause as shown in the second pair of brackets describes the posture of the people while they are making the pledge.
